# Angular TypeError: Cannot read property 'icon' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how to handle empty input on angular?

I want validate on back end not on front end.  But when i submit it return me error if i let it blank on icon input

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'icon' of undefined
```

Here is my form:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-material form-material-danger">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" ng-model="menu.name" placeholder="Menu Name.." empty-to-null>
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-material form-material-danger">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="icon" ng-model="menu.icon" placeholder="Menu Icon.." >
                        <label for="icon">Icon</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is my code:

```
 var data = {
            icon: $scope.menu.icon,
            name: $scope.menu.name
        };

        AdminMenu.save(data, function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            $scope.menu = null;
            ResultService(response);
            $scope.dtInstance.reloadData();
        }, function (response) {
            ResultService(response.data);
        })
            .$promise.finally(function () {
                $scope.button_text = "Store";
                $scope.loading = false;
            });
```

Comment: this example isn't *complete*.  where is the `menu` object created, and where is the `data` object used?

Comment: Hi. Scope menu is from the view. i just take it from the ng-model. data object is get from input at front end. @Claies

Comment: ok, thanks for letting me know, but this is still not a code sample that can be tested to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.menu = null
```

When you set `menu` to null, angular can't find `menu.icon` anymore. You should do `$scope.menu = {}` if you want to "reset" it.

And, of course, don't forget to initialize `$scope.menu` before using it.

Comment: i don't want to reset it. I just want if i press submit, it submit to backend and return error from backend. Right now if i submit, it return me undefined

Comment: So what is the purpose of `$scope.menu = null` ?

Comment: is after submit. it reset the form. right now the error is at var data = {icon: $scope.menu.icon}

Comment: becuae $scope.menu is not defined before accessing it...define `$scope.menu = {}` before data